# searching for keys of minimum values within a dict

Tags: python-3.x, dictionary, key, minimum

I'm searching for a list with the keys of the minimum values within a dict.
The goal is to get the keys of the minimum value for each i.

```
#Dict:
p[i,j] = {(0,0):10, (0,1):11, (0,2):12, (1,0):20, (1,1):21, (1,2):22, (2,0):30, (2,1):31, (2,2):32}

#The list should look like this:
list = [(0,0), (1,0), (2,0)]
```

Can i do it with a loop?

```
for i in range(3):
   ...
```

Or how can i generate this list?

Comment: Why is (1,1)  the minimum value for j=1?

Comment: Yes you're right. It should be the minimum value of i=0,1,2.

Comment: In your example, neither (1,1) nor (2,2) relate to any minimal value. It is not clear what you ask.

Comment: oh, did not see my mistake. (0,0), (1,0) and (2,0) relate to the minimal values. Right?

Answer (score 0):

Sorry, I don't know exactly what you mean. Maybe you want to get the key of P which is the minimum value and this key belongs to the list. You can try the code below.

```
p = {(0,0):10, (0,1):11, (0,2):12,
     (1,0):20, (1,1):21, (1,2):22,
     (2,0):30, (2,1):31, (2,2):32}
list = [(0,0), (1,1), (2,2)]

listRes = {}
# get listRes 10:(0,0) 21:(1,1) 32:(2,2)
for j in range(len(list)):
    listRes[p[list[j]]] = list[j]

# (10, (0, 0))
print(min(listRes.items(), key=lambda x: x[0]))
```

OK, maybe I see. See the code below.

```
import sys
p = {(0,0):10, (0,1):11, (0,2):12,
     (1,0):20, (1,1):21, (1,2):22,
     (2,0):30, (2,1):31, (2,2):32}

res = []
tuple1 = ()

for i in range(3):
    minValue = sys.maxsize
    for j in range(3):
        if minValue>p[(i,j)]:
            tuple1 = (i,j)
            minValue = p[(i,j)]
    res.append(tuple1)
print(res)
```

Comment: Thank you for the answer! Sorry for my misunderstanding. I edited the situation. I'm looking for the key for the minimum value for each i. That means the list should look like this: List= [(0,0), (1,0), (2,0)]. I hope this makes it clear.

Comment: Sorry, I still don't understand why your result are List= [(0,0), (1,0), (2,0)].

Comment: For i = 0 (j=0,1,2), the minimum value is 10, so i need the key (0,0). For i = 1 the minimum value is 20 -> key (1,0) and for i = 3 the minimum value is 30 -> key (2,0). Hope this helps you.

Comment: I've revised the answer, but I'm not good at python. There should be more general and concise code.

Comment: that's exactly what i'm looking for. Thank you a lot!

Comment: I'm glad to be able to help you.